# C++ Map Iteration and Stack Corruption

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory, dictionary, corruption

I am trying to use a system of maps to store and update data for a chat server. The application is mutlithreaded and uses a lock system to prevent multiple threads from accessing the data.

The problem is this: when a client is removed individually from the map, it is ok. However, when I try to call multiple closes, it leaves some in the memory. If I at any point call ::clear() on the map, it causes a debug assertion error with either "Iterator not compatible" or similar. The code will work the first time (tested using 80+ consoles connected as a test), but due to it leaving chunks behind, will not work again. I have tried researching ways, and I have written systems to stop the code execution until each process has completed. I appreciate any help so far, and I have attached the relevant code snippets.

```
//portion of server code that handles shutting down
DWORD WINAPI runserver(void *params) {  
    runserverPARAMS *p = (runserverPARAMS*)params;  
    /*Server stuff*/                            

    serverquit = 0; 
    //client based cleanup
    vector<int> tokill;
    map<int,int>::iterator it = clientsockets.begin();

    while(it != clientsockets.end()) {      
        tokill.push_back(it->first);
        ++it;
    }
    for(;;) {
        for each (int x in tokill) {
            clientquit[x] = 1;
            while(clientoffline[x] != 1) {
                //haulting execution until thread has terminated
            }
            destoryclient(x);
        }
    }
    //client thread based cleanup complete.
    return 0;
}


//clientioprelim
DWORD WINAPI clientioprelim(void* params) {
    CLIENTthreadparams *inparams = (CLIENTthreadparams *)params;
    /*Socket stuff*/
    for(;;) {       
        /**/
        }
        else {
            if(clientquit[inparams->clientid] == 1)
                break;
        }
    }
    clientoffline[inparams->clientid] = 1;
    return 0;
}

int LOCKED; //exported as extern via libraries.h so it's visible to other source files

void destoryclient(int clientid) {
    for(;;) {
        if(LOCKED == 0) {
            LOCKED = 1;         
            shutdown(clientsockets[clientid], 2);
            closesocket(clientsockets[clientid]);
            if((clientsockets.count(clientid) != 0) && (clientsockets.find(clientid) != clientsockets.end()))
                clientsockets.erase(clientsockets.find(clientid));                  
            if((clientname.count(clientid) != 0) && (clientname.find(clientid) != clientname.end()))
                clientname.erase(clientname.find(clientid));
            if((clientusername.count(clientid) != 0) && (clientusername.find(clientid) != clientusername.end()))
                clientusername.erase(clientusername.find(clientid));
            if((clientaddr.count(clientid) != 0) && (clientaddr.find(clientid) != clientaddr.end()))
                clientaddr.erase(clientusername.find(clientid));
            if((clientcontacts.count(clientid) != 0) && (clientcontacts.find(clientid) != clientcontacts.end())) 
                clientcontacts.erase(clientcontacts.find(clientid));
            if((clientquit.count(clientid) != 0) && (clientquit.find(clientid) != clientquit.end()))
                clientquit.erase(clientquit.find(clientid));    
            if((clientthreads.count(clientid) != 0) && (clientthreads.find(clientid) != clientthreads.end())) 
                clientthreads.erase(clientthreads.find(clientid));
            LOCKED = 0;
            break;          
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: What language is this that has a `for each`?

Comment: my `Visual C++` did that with `for each`...

Comment: Visual C++ has a non-standard `for each` extension: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xey702bw%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you really using an `int` for locking or was it just a simplification of the code? If you really use an `int`: this won't work and the critical section can be entered twice (or more) simultaneously, if both threads check the variable before one assigns to it (simplified). See [mutexes in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) for reference. You could either use some sort of mutex provided by windows or [boost thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html) instead of the `int`.

Comment: I was in fact using an int. I will research mutux objects more (I have found some MSDN artices about it).

Comment: Yes, the "for each" through me off. I was always used to "foreach".

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I am using MUTEX functions and WaitForSingleObject rather than another map for client thread termination. Works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: @CollinBiedenkapp than it would be great if you could accept the answer :)